# Django + docker + periodic commands

Tags: django, docker, periodic-task

What's the best practices for running periodic/scheduled tasks ( like manage.py custom_command ) when running Django with docker (docker-compose) ?

f.e. the most common case - [./manage.py clearsessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-clearsessions)

- Django recommends to run it with cronjobs...
- But Docker does not recommend adding more then one running service to single container...

I guess I can create a docker-compose service from the same image for each command that i need to run - and the command should run infinite loop with a needed sleeps, but that seems overkill doing that for every command that need to be scheduled

What's your advice ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up using this project - Ofelia

https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia

so you just add it to your docker-compose

and have config like:

```
[job-exec "task name"]
schedule = @daily
container = myprojectname_1
command = python ./manage.py clearsessions
```

Answer (score 6):

The way that worked for me

in my django project I have a crontab file like this:

```
0 0 * * * root python manage.py clearsessions     > /proc/1/fd/1 2>/proc/1/fd/2
```

Installed/configured cron inside my Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron
ADD crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
```

and in docker-compose.yml add a new service that will build same image as django project but will run `cron -f` as `CMD`

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./myprojectname
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    #...


  cronjobs:
    build: ./myprojectname
    command: ["cron", "-f"]
```

Comment: Also, for anyone reading this: don't do my mistakes

1) Don't add the `crontab` file as a volume. It will have a broken owner and unexpected permissions.

2) Don't expect to see your crontab in the `crontab -l`. This command ignores `cron.d` dir.

Comment: I am getting this error python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Create one docker image with your Django application.

You can use it to run your Django app (the web interface), and at the same time, using cron schedule your period tasks by passing in the command to the docker executable, like this:

```
docker exec --rm your_container python manage.py clearsessions
```

The `--rm` will make sure that docker removes the container once it finishes; otherwise you will quickly have containers stopped that are of no use.

You can also pass in any extra arguments, for example using `-e` to modify the environment:

```
docker exec --rm -e DJANGO_DEBUG=True -e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=production \
python manage.py clearsessions
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I would go for if my project was just one docker image.. but in my case it's a docker-compose with multiple images (django, redis, postgres, api) - and it would be nice if the scheduled tasks would be also dfined in docker-compose instead of host machine..

Comment: There is no point in defining the tasks in docker-compose, as its job is to orchestrate and start (and stop) the containers.