# Running crond as root user when server is going to be running as non-root django container

Tags: django, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I'm currently dockerizing my app and am trying to get cron jobs working. For context I am creating my job using the python-crontab module. I would like to run the container as a non-root user (as I believe is best practice) however I am struggling to get the cron task to run.
This is the relevant part of my current dockerfile:

```
#########
# FINAL #
#########

#Pull base image
FROM python:3.9.15-alpine3.16

#Create directory for app user
RUN mkdir -p /home/user

#create app user
RUN addgroup -S app && adduser -S useradmin -G app


#create directories
ENV HOME=/home/user
ENV APP_HOME=/home/user/userapp
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/static
RUN mkdir $APP_HOME/media
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

#install dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add libpq
COPY --from=builder /user/wheels /wheels
RUN pip install --no-cache /wheels/*

# copy entrypoint.sh
COPY entrypoint.sh $APP_HOME

# copy project
COPY . $APP_HOME

RUN python /$APP_HOME/user/cron.py
RUN crontab -l > /home/user/crontab.txt
RUN crond -f -L /dev/stdout


# chown all the files to the app user
RUN chown -R user:app $APP_HOME

# change to app user
USER useradmin

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/user/userapp/entrypoint.sh"]
```

The line `RUN crond -f -L /dev/stdout` is the only way so far I have found to get the cron jobs to execute correctly however this effectively stops the build process.

My entrypoint.sh file is pretty much as you would expect:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Running Django management commands..."

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

echo "Applying database migrations..."
python manage.py migrate --no-input
echo "Collecting static files..."
python manage.py collectstatic --no-input

echo "Starting Gunicorn..."
echo "Importing manufacturers..."
exec "$@"
```

If I try adding say `crond -L /dev/stdout` to the entrypoint and remove the crond start from the dockerfile, nothing happens after the allotted time (for debugging I've set the job to execute every 2 minutes where it will stdout and send me an email) even though when I run `ps -ef | grep crond` I can see what I believe to be crond running and when I check the crontab.txt file I created listing the cronjobs created it is in there.

If I try opening a terminal and running the `crond -f -L /dev/stdout` command I get permission denied errors:

```
crond: crond (busybox 1.35.0) started, log level 8
crond: root: Permission denied
```

however if I run the command directly without it being a cron job (i.e. I run the exact sequence of commands I would expect the cron job to perform) it works perfectly.

If anyone has any ideas I would be super grateful.

Comment: Best practice for docker is to run only one process for each container. You are trying to run two. You could go for a process manager like supervisord as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/#use-a-process-manager) or embed the cron to django via [django-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/)

Comment: `crond` probably needs to be the container's `CMD`.  As @Tarquinius suggests you should run only one process per container, but it's easy to run two containers from the same image, overriding the command on one of them (if you're using Compose, with the same `build:` setup but a different `command:`).

Comment: @DavidMaze I am indeed using compose, so I should effectively copy and paste my current "django" container, and change both the dockerfile and the command?

Comment: Use a single Dockerfile and the same `build:` block for both containers.  Set the image's `CMD` to some reasonable default, like running the Django application, but for the cron container override the Compose `command:`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47077088) has a basic example of it.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze took your advice though tweaked the dockerfile used to remove the secondary user to ensure the crond service works on root, while also improving build time.
Much appreciated both of you.